# How can I delete table row with if statement?

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to delete specific row according to my if statement. In my code delete only last row of tableview. I tried all rows in index path but its delete only last row. My code is very very complex so I can't post all in here but here my if statement. I delete also my data source array.
How can I delete specific row at tableview? Without commit editing.

```
                if userIndir < 1 {
                    self.userIndirim = "0"
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 1) // HERE I TRY ALL ROWS.
                    self.section1NumberOfRowsArr.remove(at: 1)
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    
                    
                    
                }else{
                    self.userIndirim = snapshot.value! as! String
                }
    
             }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is always better to not use the deleteRows() or insertRow() methods directly.

**Step 1:** When your condition in your if statement becomes true, you need to delete the item in your array. I guess it is 'section1NumberOfRowsArr'.

**Step 2:** After you deleted the specific item from the array, you need to reload the section which were containing the deleted row.
For reloading, don't reload the tableView with reloadData().That's fine only if you would have 1 section.
If you have multiple sections, reload only the section which is affected by the deletion.

Use the reloadSections(_:with:) method of the tableView.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614954-reloadsections

You can also specify the reloading animation style to iOS with the method above.

Comment: I have static data on that row actually. I have array but its for count purpose only so I need to hide that row. In my code can delete last row correctly but I need to delete third one so do you know any solution? How can I delete or hide that row?

Comment: *It is always better to not use the deleteRows() or insertRow() methods directly* is a pretty bold statement. What is the reason for not to use them?

Comment: In your case I would build a new array then which is used only for rendering the tableView.
If your new array changes (item added or deleted), then the reloadSections() should happen. I'm always using a separate array for the data of the tableView. So the numberOfRows is always the count of items in this array! If I need to have sections as well, I'm using a 2 level deep array like this: var listItemsForTableView: [Int: [ItemModel]]
Where the keys (Int) are the sections, and the [ItemModel] is an array of ItemModel structs.

Comment: "deleteRows() or insertRow() methods directly is a pretty bold statement. "
In my experience I never needed them. Reloading a section will only cause a nice refresh. So I guess you can use them safely if you would like to.

Comment: I see but I have complex structure and I don't want to change it now. How can I delete or hide that row at tableview?

Comment: You can use the deleteRows() method. But how will you keep track if it's deleted by the user? You need to store the actual rows of the current tableView somewhere.
Otherwise when your user deletes a row - then navigates away and comes back to this screen - the row won't be deleted. The user needs to delete it again?

Comment: I didn't give downvote. Actually my users can't figure out deleted row because I check my database and according to data I want to hide or show that row so when user re-open that page same function is trigger and user can't see row again.

Comment: Ok, since you have the database as the storage (not an array in your ViewController), you only need to delete the selected row (by some kind of ID) when your IF condition happens. Then reload the section which was affected.